# How to make java recognize unreachable code and stop with compile errors

Tags: java, refactoring

I'm working in a big legacy project and I'm still learning about clean code in java and trying to apply some good manners that I already know. Nevertheless, I tried to write a method like I write in others languages (like Rust), avoiding unnecessary variables, etc...
But in this case below it can't compile it without the unreachable *return null* outside the try-catch block.

```java
    private Inet4Address setServerAddress() {
        try {
            if (somethingTrue()) {
                return (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            }

            return (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName(getIP4());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Error at getting the server address from " +
                    "command line. (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /* Unreachable */
        return null;
    }
```

I choose to use the `System.exit(1)` because as this is the terminal part of the application, I wouldn't like to see a big java exception message, but only something that made sense for the user.

So my question is, how can I make javac understand that there isn't any case that this function won't return something. I really don't like to keep a return null in my code, even if it will never run.

Comment: You can't. The Java compiler doesn't understand that `System.exit(...)` never returns normally. To the compiler, it's just another method call like any other.

Comment: Just printing e.getMessage() may seem friendlier to the user, but it's going to make life hard for you when the user asks what's wrong. You should at least have a log file where the whole stack trace is written.

Comment: what if you add `throw new AssertionError("should not be reached")` or similar after the `System.exit(1)`

Comment: Okay, that does it, thank you very much! @user16320675

Comment: BTW be aware that `System.exit()` (when not dis-allowed) will always stop the whole Virtual Machine, not only the actual Thread - will eventually also *cancel* shutdown hooks and similar

Comment: I see, is there a way to keep the simple error message using the `throw` or it will always show the default message + stack trace? `System.exit(1)` really seems like a wrong thing to do in java.

Comment: maybe write a new (customized) **checked** exception and declare the method to throw it - so the caller, or its caller (depending where it is appropriate), must deal with it and can then display a better message. (you can also use an existing exception, but it must be a checked one to force it to be handled - in posted code I would eventually just throw the `UnknownHostException`, but I do not know the rest of the code)

Comment: I see, it seems like the best option right now, I'm going to read more about the creation of this checked exception and try to apply it. My intention on exiting in the method was because it runs at the constructor, so the `System.exit()` occurs before any real logic in the program.

Comment: "create a checked exception": basically you need to extend Exception: `public class MyException extends Exception { ... }` and add some constructor that calls the correct constructor of `Exception` (using a better name as I did here)

Answer (score 2):

Calling `System.exit()` down in the bowels of your code makes it hard to reuse this method.

I would have this method throw an exception (you can simply not catch the UnknownHostException) and have a try-catch at the top level of your tool (I'm assuming that "this is the terminal part of the application" means that this is a command line tool?), probably in your main method.

That allows you to put a standard way of handling all run time errors in a single place.

The exception could be an unchecked exception, or if you want to make the API clearer, make a new checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

any advanced IDE such as Eclipse can show unreachable code as a warning after compilation that shows up in Problems tab. In addition a Eclipse SpotBug plugin static analysis tool can find more sophisticated cases.

Comment: Don't think _detecting_ unreachable code is the OP's goal. They want to omit the `return null` statement, and have `javac` recognize the statement isn't necessary and therefore still compile without errors. The problem, of course, is that the Java compiler doesn't do that sort of analysis.

Comment: @João you don't want to "*stop javac from making the missing return statement a error*", it is more like you want javac to not request the return statement, or?

Comment: I want to learn a way to make the javac see the code after the returns as a unreachable code, if I put a 'throw(something)', the error goes away and the 'return null' is unnecessary, but it shows an "ugly message".

Comment: @João you want to "*make the javac see the code after the returns as a unreachable code*" - that is always the case, code after a return is unreachable! Which "ugly message"?

Comment: The ugly message is the stack trace or an exception default message, that doesn't say too much to the user.

Comment: @João but that Exception should never be thrown... unless something was messing with the `exit()` method - `exit()` is documented to never terminate normally, that is, or it stops the VM or it throws a `SecurityException` (or [extremely seldom] some other `Error`)